# Activity doesn't inherit parent style

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-theme, appcompatactivity

I am converting my app from using ActionBarSherlock to AppCompat. My activities that extend AppCompatActivity don't appear to be inheriting the parent style by default. To explain:

This is styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

This is how the class ChooseFunction is declared:

```
public class ChooseFunction extends AppCompatActivity
{
...
}
```

This is part of AndroidManifest.xml (some activities removed):

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.enborne.spine"
    android:versionCode="19"
    android:versionName="2.3" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Spine"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoadData"
            android:label="@string/loading_data" />
        <activity android:name=".ChooseFunction"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"/>
        <activity android:name=".DownloadNotams"
            android:label="@string/downloading_notams" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The problem is that if I remove the explicit theme attribute from the ChooseFunction activity in the manifest, I get the error "You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity."

Now since AppTheme inherits from Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar, and the default theme for the application is AppTheme, I would expect ChooseFunction to use the default, and inherit from the AppCompat theme.

I must be doing something wrong, but I cannot see what it is. I did not need to specify the theme explicitly when using ActionBarSherlock.

Comment: Do you have multiple `values*/` folders in `res/`, for different API levels? If so, is `AppTheme` correctly defined everywhere? For example, this often happens to me when I forget to remove the `AppTheme` with a `Theme.Material` parent in `values-v21/`.

Comment: @MikeM Aha! That was the main problem - I have a styles (v11) which originally had a different parent theme. I have changed it to:
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="android:buttonStyle">@android:style/Widget.Holo.Button.Small</item>
    </style>

Problem is now my background screen is light instead of dark, so there is something else wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by background screen, but I would point out that you're using a `Light` theme. Also, that theme you posted in your comment is entirely unrelated to the one you posted in the question, so when it's used, none of those `color*` attributes have been set as shown above. When using `AppCompat`, you generally only ever need themes defined in the default `values/` folder. The versioning is handled for you, unless you do want markedly different looks on different API levels, for whatever reason.

Comment: What I meant was that with the currently released version using ActionBarSherlock, on my help screens (derived from pager_adapter) I had white text (set in program) on a default dark (black) background. Now with AppCompat I have white text on a light background. If I set the background colour to black, it extends only as much as the text covers - the rest of the screen is light. Also button text was white in upper and lower case on a dark button - now it's all upper case black text on a light button. I'm going to read up on theming with AppCompat to see how to fix this. Any help here welcome!

Comment: `Light` themes are predominately light colors, and the background is usually close to flat white. If you want a predominately dark theme, then change the parent to `Theme.AppCompat`. As for the `Button` text case, that's normal for newer designs. If you don't want that, you can set `textAllCaps` to `false` in the style set as the `buttonStyle`.

Comment: @MikeM Thanks for helping so much! Now reading up on replacing the ActionBar with Toolbar. And I thought this was going to be a simple update to my app, just changing a URL. Then "update Android Studio" and "update Gradle" and it all goes to pot..